# How to align elements making them have the height of the tallest one

Tags: html, css, height

I'm creating the following pricing page in HTML and CSS

[image]

I'd like the "Choose plan" to be aligned, that is, I would need the div.header elements to have the height of the largest one, depending on the title and description of the plan.

Here's a jsfiddle with the html and css: https://jsfiddle.net/opensas/nxLbth5d/8/

And here's a jsfiddle with the solution done in js (my question is precisely how to avoid doing it with js, of course): https://jsfiddle.net/opensas/u2hcs6fm/1/

the js code:

```js
const headers = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('header'));
// get the greatest of each's header calculated height (without padding)
const maxHeight = Math.max(
    ...headers.map((h) => parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(h).getPropertyValue('height')))
);
for (const header of headers) header.style.height = `${maxHeight}px`;
```

For reference below is the whole code

How can I achieve it? preferable with plain CSS (no JavaScript)

```css
.pricing {
  font-family: Inter, ui-sans-serif, system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
  ;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.pricing .plans {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(240px, 290px));
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: stretch;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.pricing .plan {
  border: 1px solid #E5E7E9;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}

.pricing .plan .header {
  padding: 1rem;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-style: none none solid none;
  border-color: #F3F4F5;
}

.pricing .plan .header .title {
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 150%;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.pricing .plan .header .description {
  padding: 0.25rem 0 1rem 0;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  line-height: 145%;
  color: #6D7A87;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.pricing .plan .price {
  padding: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  width: fit-content;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 0.5rem;
}

.pricing .plan .price .amount {
  color: #101113;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  line-height: 120%;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.pricing .plan .price .billing-cycle {
  color: #6D7A87;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  line-height: 145%;
}

.pricing .plan .buy {
  padding: 0 1rem 1rem 1rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-style: none none solid none;
  border-color: #F3F4F5;
}

.pricing .plan .buy .buy-button {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.5rem 0 0.5rem 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  border: 1px solid #E5E7E9;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  line-height: 145%;
  color: #6D7A87;
  text-decoration: inherit;
}

.pricing .plan .features {
  padding: 1rem;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  gap: 0.5rem;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
}

.pricing .plan .features .feature {
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  line-height: 145%;
  color: #101113;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-left: 1.5rem;
}

.pricing .plan .features .feature::before {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -1.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <div id="pricing" class="pricing">

    <div class="plans">

      <div class="plan" id="PP1258915598215363">
        <div class="header">
          <div class="title">Basic service desk</div>
          <div class="description">Basic service desk support plan. For companies that just started and need help looking after their userbase.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="price">
          <span class="amount">$10</span>
          <span class="billing-cycle">billed monthly</span>
        </div>
        <div class="buy">
          <a class="buy-button" href="https://pricing.test.wingback.com/examples/null">Choose plan</a>
        </div>
        <ol class="features">
          <li class="feature">Public repositories</li>
          <li class="feature">Team Collaboration</li>
          <li class="feature">Ticket Trend Report</li>
          <li class="feature">Multiple users</li>
        </ol>
      </div>

      <div class="plan" id="PP4072474523116192">
        <div class="header">
          <div class="title">Medium service desk plan</div>
          <div class="description">For companies with a growing user base.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="price">
          <span class="amount">$18</span>
          <span class="billing-cycle">billed monthly</span>
        </div>
        <div class="buy">
          <a class="buy-button" href="https://pricing.test.wingback.com/examples/null">Choose plan</a>
        </div>
        <ol class="features">
          <li class="feature">Custom Email Server</li>
          <li class="feature">Custom Ticket Views</li>
          <li class="feature">Ticket Fields Status</li>
          <li class="feature">Collision Detection</li>
          <li class="feature">Custom SSL</li>
          <li class="feature">Time tracking</li>
        </ol>
      </div>

      <div class="plan" id="PP3070612550030584">
        <div class="header">
          <div class="title">Professional service desk with premium support</div>
          <div class="description">Professional service desk support</div>
        </div>
        <div class="price">
          <span class="amount">$60</span>
          <span class="billing-cycle">billed monthly</span>
        </div>
        <div class="buy">
          <a class="buy-button" href="https://pricing.test.wingback.com/examples/null">Choose plan</a>
        </div>
        <ol class="features">
          <li class="feature">Ticket Fields Status</li>
          <li class="feature">Custom Email Server</li>
          <li class="feature">Automation</li>
          <li class="feature">Customer Fields</li>
          <li class="feature">Custom Ticket Views</li>
          <li class="feature">Custom SSL</li>
          <li class="feature">Marketplace Apps</li>
          <li class="feature">Helpdesk Report</li>
          <li class="feature">Time tracking</li>
          <li class="feature">Collision Detection</li>
        </ol>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: have you thought the min-height option?

Comment: the min-height would help if all the plans have short descriptions, they would all be aligned according to that minimal height, But I'd like them all to have the height of the tallest one, in case one of them has a longer description or title.
Can I set the height of them to be the height of tallest one?